# How to add collection view into a table view as cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a JSON file (as an API) that I have fetched. The data is NFTs and I want to present the values of the NFTs in my ViewController. I have made a table view that generates custom cells and that makes a list of the NFTs but now I want to customise  my project a little more by adding a collection view in a cell of the tableView. In this collection view I want to put the creators of the NFTs. I have stacked because in my eyes I have done the proccesss right but in the end the things don't appear in my screen.

I will give you the code that I wrote to see if someone can help me. The whole idea is that in the "first cell" I want to have the collection view and under this I want to have a list of my NFTs (the list made by custom cells on AssetTableViewCell).

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class LobbyViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - IBProperties

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Properties

    var data: [DataEnum] = []
    var likes:[Int] = []
    var numlikes: Int = 0
    var nfts: [Nft] = []
    var creators : [Creator] = []
    var users: [User] = []
    var icons: [Icon] = []
    var loadData = APICaller()

    // MARK: - Life Cyrcle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(AssetTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AssetTableViewCell")
        tableView.register(CreatorsTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CreatorsTableViewCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self //method to generate cells,header and footer before they are displaying
        tableView.delegate = self //method to provide information about these cells, header and footer ....

        downloadJSON {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("success")
        }
        loadData.downloadData { (result) in
           // print(result)
            print("success")
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? NftListViewController {
            destination.nft = nfts[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row]
            destination.delegate = self
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Methods

    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://public.arx.net/~chris2/nfts.json")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in

            if error == nil {
                do {

                    self.nfts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Nft].self, from: data!)
                    self.creators = try JSONDecoder().decode([Creator].self, from: data!)

                    self.creators.forEach{ creator in
                        self.data.append(.type1(creators: creator))
                    }

                    self.nfts.forEach { nft in
                        self.data.append(.type2(nft: nft))
                    }
                    print(self.nfts)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("error fetching data from api")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions

extension LobbyViewController : UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20.0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    //orizo ton arithmo ton rows tou table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section : Int) ->Int {
        return data.count
    }

    //gemizo ta rows tou table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch self.data[indexPath.item] {
        case .type1(let creator):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CreatorsTableViewCell",
                                                     for: indexPath) as! CreatorsTableViewCell
            let creator = creators[indexPath.row]
            cell.creatorNames?.text = creator.user.username
            let crImg = (creator.profileImgURL)
            //print(crImg)
            cell.creImg.download(from: crImg)
            return UITableViewCell()
        case .type2(let nft):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AssetTableViewCell",
                                                     for: indexPath) as! AssetTableViewCell

            let nft = nfts[indexPath.row]
            cell.nameLabel?.text = nft.name
            cell.nameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = cell.nameLabel.frame.height/2
            cell.likesLabel?.text = "\((numlikes))"
            let imgUrl = (nft.image_url)
            print(imgUrl)
            cell.iconView.download(from: imgUrl)
            cell.iconView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.iconView.frame.height/2
            return cell
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }
}

extension LobbyViewController : TestDelegate{
    func sendBackTheLikess(int: Int) {
        numlikes = int
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func download(from url: URL, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200, let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"), let data = data, error == nil, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                self?.image = image

            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func download(from link: String, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }

        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Enums
enum DataEnum { case type1(creators: Creator) case type2(nft: Nft) }

// MARK: - Struct
struct Constants { static let url = "https://public.arx.net/~chris2/nfts.json" }
```

CreatorTableViewCell

```
import UIKit
    
class CreatorsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: -- IBProperties
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var creatorNames: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var creImg: UIImageView!
    
    //MARK: -- Properties
    var creators : Creator?
    var users : User?
    static let identifier = "CreatorsTableViewCell"
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    //MARK: -- Functions
    static func nib() -> UINib{ return UINib(nibName: "CreatorsTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
}

    // MARK: - Extensions
    
extension UIImageView { func downloadImgs(from url: URL, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) { contentMode = mode URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in guard let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200, let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"), let data = data, error == nil, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return } DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in self?.image = image } }.resume() } func downloadImgs(from link: String, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) { guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return } downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode) } }
```

AssetTableViewCell

```
import UIKit
    
class AssetTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: -- IBProperties
    
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var iconView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var likesLabel: UILabel!
    
    //MARK: -- Properties
    
    var nfts:Nft?
    static let identifier = "AssetTableViewCell"
    //MARK: -- Life Cyrcle
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        nameLabel.layer.cornerRadius = nameLabel.frame.height/2
        likesLabel.layer.cornerRadius = likesLabel.frame.height/2
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    //MARK: -- Functions
    
    static func nib() -> UINib{
         return UINib(nibName: "AssetTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    }
}
```

Models

```
import Foundation

    // MARK: - Nft struct Nft: Codable{ let id:Int let image_url:String let name:String let creator: Creator }
    
    // MARK: - Icon struct Icon:Codable{ let image_url:String }
    
    // MARK: - Creator struct Creator: Codable { let user: User let profileImgURL: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user
        case profileImgURL = "profile_img_url"
    
    }
}
    
    // MARK: - User struct User: Codable { let username: String? }
```

APICaller

```
//
//  APICaller.swift
//  Nft Assets
//
//  Created by Ben Seferidis on 11/10/22

import Foundation
    
final class APICaller {
    static let shared = APICaller()
    
    public struct Constants {
        static let url = "https://public.arx.net/~chris2/nfts.json"
    }
    
    public func downloadData(completion:@escaping (Result<[Nft], Error>) -> Void )
    {
        guard let url = URL(string:Constants.url)else{
            return
        }
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
           //print(response)
            print("here")
            guard let data = data , error == nil else{
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            print("here4")
            //mexri edo exoume parei ta data kai tora me to do-catch tha ta kanoume convert se object
            do{
                //Decode the response
                let nfts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Nft].self, from: data)
                completion(.success(nfts))
                print(nfts)
            }catch{
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to use collection view with compositional Layout.

Comment: You've shown a lot of code (but you're designing cells/views in IB so we have no way of knowing if you've done that right), and you say *"in the end the things don't appear in my screen"* ... Are you not getting *anything*? Are you getting empty rows? Are you getting rows with collection views but no cells? Or cells, but nothing in them? In your post I see `cellForRowAt` but I don't see any collection view code for `cellForItemAt`?

Comment: Your `CreatorsTableViewCell.collectionView` has no dataSource, so there is no way it could display any data, and also your `tableView(cellForRow` is just returning `UITableViewCell()` for that cell anyway.

Comment: I am not getting anything the rows don't generates

Comment: @BenSef - ok... you're missing several pieces, as you haven't given your collection view a dataSource or delegate, and you have no code providing anything to the collection view (unless you do but haven't shown it). First step should always be **searching** ... head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `uicollectionview inside uitableviewcell` -- you'll find lots of blogs, articles, examples, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement CollectionView Datasource and Delegate code in CreatorsTableViewCell.
Also, try to change `indexPath.item` to `indexPath.row` if it's dealing with TableView.